# How do I change the theme of a record page to have a gradient background?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, custom-theme-layout

I want to setup a gradient background and not use the themes that are available with SF. I tried creating a new theme where it takes a background image but that is shown only in the top of the screen after the header. I saw that community page have themes where complete page's background can be modified, I tried creating a custom template but that did not work for me as the template had my background on top of the SF them.

is there a way i can achieve this? 
[image: Custom template]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the lighting experience theme as you would a lightning community, you can create content layouts, however, these, as you pointed out only appear below the header on top of the lighting experience background (or without the header, depending on your use case).

So, at the moment, this is not possible.